Overlapping a gradient with a repeating-linear-gradient in css
What I was able to do:

What I want:

I want to add those white lines. I need exactly 25 of them spread out evenly, regardless of the size of the element.
Here is the code:
.div {
    height: 50px;
    background-image: 
    repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, transparent 10px, white 10px, white 14px),
    linear-gradient(90deg,#ff5e6d,#ffd255,#92d6a5);
}

I have tried using the calc() function in CSS, but I could not make it work.

Try the following


.box {
  --b: 5px; /* width of the bar */
  --n: 10;  /* number of bars */
  
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(90deg,#fff var(--b),#0000 0)
    calc(-1*var(--b))/calc((100% + var(--b))/(var(--n) + 1)) 100%, 
    linear-gradient(90deg,#ff5e6d, #ffd255, #92d6a5);
}
<div class="box"></div>



